# Trivial divisor on elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

Suppose $E$ is an elliptic curve over $k$, and $(E,+)$ is an abelian group(suppose we fix some closed point as identity). Let $[p]$ denote the Weil divisor corresponding to the closed point $p \in  E$.

It is claimed that for any closed point $p_0, p, a \in E$, the Weil divisor $$[p_0 + a]+[p]-[p_0]-[a+p]$$ is trivial.

I know how to show this when $k = \mathbb{C}$: the proof uses the residue of periodic function and basically it says that for a Weil divisor to be trivial iff (1) the number of zeros equal to the number of poles and (2) the sum of zeros equal to the sum of poles. However, I don't know how to show this for arbitrary field. I guess one might use Riemann-Roth in some way, but did not figure out what to do.

Comment: Don’t you know something about the group structure? Namely, how it is defined?

Comment: Isn't this a consequence of the fact that, for elliptic curves, the usual group law concides with the group law induced by the isomorfism $E \simeq {\rm Pic^0(E)}$, given by $P \to (P)-(O)$?

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean!